# R Summarise dplyr grouped data with certain rows excluded based on another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to summarize data across multiple columns, based on all rows **other than** rows with a certain value in a separate grouping variable column. For example, in the df below, I want to get the medians of A, B, C, D, and E based on values from rows that are not assigned to the cluster matching a given row.

```
df = data.frame(cluster = c(1:5, 1:3, 1:2),
                    A = rnorm(10, 2),
                    B = rnorm(10, 5),
                    C = rnorm(10, 0.4),
                    D = rnorm(10, 3),
                    E = rnorm(10, 1))

df %>%
group_by(cluster) %>%
summarise_at(toupper(letters[1:5]), funs(m = fun_i_need_help_with(.)))
```

fun_i_need_help_with would give the equivalent of:

```
    first row: median(df[which(df$cluster != 1), "A"])
    second row: median(df[which(df$cluster != 2), "A"])
    and so on...
```

I can do it with nested for loops, but it's pretty slow to run and doesn't seem like a good R-like solution.

```
for(col in toupper(letters[1:5])){
    for(clust in unique(df$cluster)){
        df[which(df$cluster == clust), col] <-
           median(df[which(df$cluster != clust), col])
     }
    }
```

Comment: Random note: `LETTERS[1:5]` is the same as `toupper(letters[1:5])`

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using the `tidyverse`.

```
set.seed(123)

df = data.frame(cluster = c(1:5, 1:3, 1:2),
                A = rnorm(10, 2),
                B = rnorm(10, 5),
                C = rnorm(10, 0.4),
                D = rnorm(10, 3),
                E = rnorm(10, 1))

library(tidyverse)

df2 <- map_dfr(unique(df$cluster),
        ~df %>%
          filter(cluster != .x) %>%
          summarize_at(vars(-cluster), funs(median(.))) %>%
          # Add a label to show the content of this row is not from a certain cluster number
          mutate(not_cluster = .x))
df2
#          A        B          C        D         E not_cluster
# 1 2.070508 5.110683  0.1820251 3.553918 0.7920827           1
# 2 2.070508 5.400771 -0.6260044 3.688640 0.5333446           2
# 3 1.920165 5.428832 -0.2769652 3.490191 0.8543568           3
# 4 1.769823 5.400771 -0.2250393 3.426464 0.5971152           4
# 5 1.769823 5.400771 -0.3288912 3.426464 0.5971152           5
```

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly as I hoped. I'll have to read a bit about map_dfr so that I really understand what's happening there.